# When recieving more than 4 characters the function is called twice

Tags: c, raspberry-pi-pico

My code is an interrupt which reads the UART. When character count is greater than 4, `data_processing` is called twice. When the background task is polled every 100ms, `data_processing` can process the whole string but if I change to a continuos loop this problem occurs. How can I pass the whole string?

```
void UART_Rx(){
     //The led on PICO blinks when it receives data.

    irq_clear(UART0_IRQ);
    char Rx[4]="";
    /*Process the received signal from UART Rx*/
    int i=0;
    while (uart_is_readable(uart0)&&i<4){
        Rx[i]=uart_getc(uart0);
        if(Rx[i]=='>'){
            break;
        }
        i++ ;
        /*if((Rx[i]==' ')){
            printf("This is a test");
        }
        if(Rx[i]!=' '||Rx[i]!='\n'||Rx[i]!='\r'){
            if (Rx[i]=='>'){
            gpio_put(LED_PIN, 1);//for indication
            gpio_put(LED_PIN, 0);
            strcpy(Rec,Rx);
            uart_puts(uart0,Rx);
            uart_puts(uart0,Rec);
            data_processing(Rx);
            memset(Rx,0,strlen(Rx));
            memset(Rec,0,strlen(Rec));
            i=-1;
        }
            i++;
        }
      */

    }
    busy_wait_ms(10);
    data_processing(Rx);
    strcpy(Rec,Rx);
}
void data_processing(char *Rx){

process data
}
```

Comment: Well UART_Rx() has an internal limit of 4 characters, why do you expect it to do more at a time? Also `string` functions are highly suspicious here as you don't terminate your buffer.

Comment: `strcpy(Rec,Rx);` Rx is very unlikely to be null character terminated C string

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy(Rec,Rx)` expects `Rx` contains a *string*.  `Rx[i]=uart_getc(uart0);` does not certainly assign a *null character*, thus the `strcpy()` call is UB.

Perhaps use `memcpy(Rec, Rx, 4);`, yet need to see the larger code for a better answer.